# Determining the values of the filter matrices in a CNN

Tags: deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am getting started with deep learning and have a basic question on CNN's.
I understand how gradients are adjusted using backpropagation according to a loss function.
But I thought the values of the convolving filter matrices (in CNN's) needs to be determined by us.

I'm using Keras and this is how (from a tutorial) the convolution layer was defined:

```
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
```

There are 32 filter matrices with dimensions 3x3 is used.

But, how are the values for these 32x3x3 matrices are determined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the gradients that are adjusted, the gradient calculated with the backpropagation algorithm is just the group of partial derivatives with respect to each weight in the network, and these components are in turn used to adjust the network weights in order to minimize the loss.

Take a look at this [introductive guide](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html).

The weights in the convolution layer in your example will be initialized to random values (according to a specific method), and then tweaked during training, using the gradient at each iteration to adjust each individual weight. Same goes for weights in a fully connected layer, or any other layer with weights.

**EDIT**: I'm adding some more details about the answer above.

Let's say you have a neural network with a single layer, which has some weights W. Now, during the forward pass, you calculate your output yHat for your network, compare it with your expected output y for your training samples, and compute some cost C (for example, using the quadratic cost function).

Now, you're interested in making the network more accurate, ie. you'd like to minimize C as much as possible. Imagine you want to find the minimum value for simple function like f(x)=x^2. You can start at some random point (as you did with your network), then compute the slope of the function at that point (ie, the derivative) and move down that direction, until you reach a minimum value (a local minimum at least).

With a neural network it's the same idea, with the difference that your inputs are fixed (the training samples), and you can see your cost function C as having n variables, where n is the number of weights in your network. To minimize C, you need the slope of the cost function C in each direction (ie. with respect to each variable, each weight w), and that vector of partial derivatives is the gradient.

Once you have the gradient, the part where you "move a bit following the slope" is the weights update part, where you update each network weight according to its partial derivative (in general, you subtract some learning rate multiplied by the partial derivative with respect to that weight).

A trained network is just a network whose weights have been adjusted over many iterations in such a way that the value of the cost function C over the training dataset is as small as possible.

This is the same for a convolutional layer too: you first initialize the weights at random (ie. you place yourself on a random position on the plot for the cost function C), then compute the gradients, then "move downhill", ie. you adjust each weight following the gradient in order to minimize C.

The only difference between a fully connected layer and a convolutional layer is how they calculate their outputs, and how the gradient is in turn computed, but the part where you update each weight with the gradient is the same for every weight in the network.

So, to answer your question, those filters in the convolutional kernels are initially random and are later adjusted with the backpropagation algorithm, as described above.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Sergio. I am still not clear on the answer but started reading the guide you provided. It is a very clearly detailed guide and already learned a lot of insight. Thank you for that.

Comment: @madu Hello, I've added some more info to my answer, don't forget to mark it as valid answer for your question if it was useful to you! 

Comment: Thank you. The update helped me clear some confusion. Can you please let me know this. For CNN's, the values of the convolution kernel matrix are the weights? After the filtering with the kernel matrix, then the result is fed to an activation function like ReLU, and the result goes to the activation map?

Answer (score 1):

Sergio0694 states ,"The weights in the convolution layer in your example will be initialized to random values". So if they are random and say I want 10 filters. Every execution algorithm could find different filter. Also say I have Mnist data set. Numbers are formed of edges and curves. Is it guaranteed that there will be a edge filter or curve filter in 10?
I mean is first 10 filters most meaningful most distinctive filters we can find.
best